$ \arctan\left(\frac{\sin\alpha + A\cos\alpha}{\cos\alpha - A\sin\alpha}\right) = \alpha + \arctan A $. Is this in fact an identity?
I found the identity at the bottom in a paper titled Nonlinear Estimation with Radar Observations by Miller and Leskiw:

I tried to prove it but I'm at a loss.
Much obliged for any pointers.
$$
\arctan\left(\frac{\sin\left(\alpha\right) + A\cos\left(\alpha\right)}{\cos\left(\alpha\right) - A\sin\left(\alpha\right)}\right) = \alpha + \arctan\left(A\right)
$$


See $\large\color{black}{\bf 4.4.34}\ \mbox{in A & S}$

As presented, the relation is not an identity. The left-hand side is bounded between $-90^\circ$ and $90^\circ$, as is the $\arctan$ on the right-hand side, but that free-floating $\alpha$ on the right is itself unbounded. So, some restrictions are needed. ... That said, taking the tangent of both sides yields a valid identity (provided everything's defined).

Welcome to Math SE. Note dividing both the numerator & denominator by $\cos(\alpha)$ gives that $\frac{\sin(\alpha)+A\cos(\alpha)}{\cos(\alpha)-A\sin(\alpha)}=\frac{\tan(\alpha)+A}{1-A\tan(\alpha)}$. Also, within certain restrictions mentioned in Blue's comment, $\alpha=\arctan(\tan(\alpha))$. Then you can use the reference provided in Felix's comment.

There may be additional conditions implied in the paper that are not included in the question.

There is a tangent angle sum formula,
$$
\tan (x \pm y) = \frac{\tan x \pm \tan y}{1 \mp \tan x \tan y}
$$
and hence, for arctangents,
$$
\arctan x \pm \arctan y = \arctan \frac{x \pm y}{1 \mp xy} \tag{$\ast$}
$$
Suppose that $x=A$ and $y=\tan \alpha$ and we choose to add $\alpha$, so the above becomes
$$
\arctan A + \alpha = \arctan \frac{A + \tan \alpha}{1 - A \tan \alpha}
$$
Multiply the top and bottom of the fraction in the arctangent function by $\cos \alpha$, noting that $\tan \alpha = \sin \alpha/\cos \alpha$.
$$
\arctan A + \alpha = \arctan \frac{A \cos \alpha + \sin \alpha}{\cos \alpha - A \sin \alpha}
$$
as desired.

Note that $(\ast)$ holds provided that the left-hand side is in $(-\frac \pi 2, \frac \pi 2)$. This necessarily restricts our variables somewhat in the obvious way.
